# Checkbox does not work in modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a checkbox into my bootstrap modal. But it doesn't appear on my page.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="checkbox">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox"/> Check me out
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

The same code works perfect in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0fscmf3L/439/).

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap css and javascript right? Could be a problem with your scripts.

Comment: It's working perfectly here. http://jsfiddle.net/0fscmf3L/443/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look with the Inspect element / Developer Tools over the modal of your browser?
Perhaps another CSS style is hiding your checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put '/' after "checkbox".

**It should be:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
</label>
```

---

If you can provide the full code of modal. That will be easier for me to check where is the mistake.

Comment: The leaving the / out of html is nothing but short code and has nothing to do with the issue. using / is perfectly fine and nothing but a preference. leaving the / out of html code wasn't even introduced until around html 4 or 5.